# Android : Activity Destroy and Thread display an AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have an activity that launches one thread which displays one AlertDialog. The problem is that if the activity is Destroyed before that thread displays the alertDialog, there is an application error(into log I read : Are you sure that the activity is running?). I can resolve this problem ?

EDIT : this is the core of the Thread

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        String read = "";
        try {
            read = useHttpPost(url);
            parseFeeds(read);
            Log.d("TVD MORE_NEWS0", "Feeds ottenuti dalla stringa JSON");
            message.obj = feeds; // come object inseriamo i feeds scaricati
            message.arg1 = 1;// come arg1 mettiamo 1, per indicare che l'operazione ha avuto successo.
        } catch (NoHttpResponseException e) {
                          //Visual ALertDialog
            message.obj = null;
            message.arg1 = -1;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            if(e.getMessage().contains("no_comm")){
                                     //Visual ALertDialog
                message.obj = null;
                message.arg1 = -2;
            }
            Log.e("TVD MORE_NEWS1", "Errore durante il parsing JSON:" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        handler.sendMessage(message);
    }
```

Comment: what is useHttpPost(). Is it a AsyncTask or any thing else.

Answer (score 1):

The Thread must check if the calling Activity is alive.

```
public class CallingActivity{
  Thread t;

  method(){
    ..
    t = new Thread();
    t.execute();
  }

  onDestroy(){
    t.interrupt();
  }
}

class Thread{
  WeakReference<Handler> handlerRef;

  run(){
    //do my work
    if(!isInterrupted()){
      handlerRef().get().performAction();
    else
      //do nothing
  }
}
```

Also note that you are introducing a potential memory leak, by letting the Thread hold on to a Handler of the Activity. I'd suggest that you hold a WeakReference to the Handler in the Thread, instead of the Handler directly.

Answer (score 0):

Just in your destroy method check if the thread is had displayed the alert dialog or not.

if the thread has not completed its task it means that thread is running and then you can manually stop the thread.

so that if the thread is in execution then it will be stoped/canceled before destroying the activity.

Comment: But also if I call thread.stop or invalidare the thread it not stop the thread in progress that must finish its work....

Comment: Yes, I have inserted the code of thread into my first answer.